# Is there any way to access fields of 'super' class (not inherited)

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, inner-classes

Title may be misleading as I had some trouble searching and even creating a proper question, so let me give a real problem I'm struggling with:

I have a `Graph` class. Since graphs need nodes and edges I created two additional classes `Node` (vertex) and `Edge`. My structure looks like this:

```
class Graph
{
    List<Node> nodes;
    List<Edge> edges;

    public Graph( ... ) { /* populate lists */ }
}

class Node { ... }
class Edge { ... }
```

I wrote some methods for `Node` class, one is particularly problematic for me. Signature:

```
public List<Node> GetNeighbours(List<Edge> edges) { ... }
```

Pretty standard. Given a graph I ask a node: how many neighbours do you have? I need list of edges to resolve it.

How can I refactor this code so that I can use `Graph` properties/fields inside instead of passing a list of edges every time? Is something like this possible:

```
public List<Node> GetNeighbours()
{
    // ...
    foreach(edge in *BASE*.edges) { ... }
}
```

I know that I can't use the `base` keyword because I don't want any inheritance here (why would a node have to inherit from graph?!) and nested classes seem not to help me as well (no access to "parent's" fields).

This code is working right now, but I feel it's not elegant and I'd like to experience a proper solution.

Comment: You need to pass the "parent" class itself.

Comment: @SLaks So basically I need to create additional `Graph` inside the `Node` class? It's impossible to do "Graphs is my parent and I want his edges"? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: How about when constructing the graph, each Node would contain a reference to each edge that is connected to it, and each edge would have a reference to the nodes on both ends. That you would not need to do all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a reference to the parent class in the `Graph` constructor.

Something like:

```
class Graph
{
    private ParentType parent;

    public void Graph(ref ParentType parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Then, in the `GetNeighbours` method (assuming the `ParentType` has an `Edges` collection property):

```
public List<Node> GetNeighbours()
{
    // ...
    foreach(var edge in parent.Edges) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this does the trick. When I used `Graph` method it modified `ParentType` (an object of this class to be precise) fields. I didn't know that it's passed by reference (missing `ref` keyword).

Comment: @rsqLVo - It's not passed by reference unless the `ref` keyword is used.  It's passed by value and in the case of a reference type, a copy of the reference is passed.

Comment: Nice catch @ChrisDunaway, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

From this description of what you're trying to do:

> Given a graph I ask a node: how many neighbours do you have?

Are you sure that this should be a method of a `Node`? Since `Graph` contains the `Nodes` and `Edges` perhaps this method is better off in `Graph`.

```
public List<Node> GetNeighbours(Node node)
{
    if(!nodes.Contains(node)
    {
        return new List<Node>(); //No neighbors. Return an empty list.
    }
    // Find and return the neighbors. This method is in Graph so it
    // has access to all of Graph's internals.
}
```

My reasoning is that since in a sense `Graph` is a parent and it contains `Nodes`, `Node` does not need to know about `Graph`. Its purpose (Single Responsibility) is complete without any references to `Graph`.

Comment: That's a good point. My approach came out of a need to colour a specific `Node` so from a wider perspective I was looking at "I want to be red, but I need to check my neighbours first" :) Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would have a method like `Graph.AddNodes()` or `Graph.AddEdges()` on `Graph` so that this is a central place to make sure that all `Nodes` (and/or `Edges`) have the reference that it needs.  I'm thinking something like this, depending on the model of `Node` and `Edge` for you.

```
class Graph
{
    List<Node> nodes;
    List<Edge> edges;

    public Graph( ... ) { /* populate lists */ }

    public void AddEdges(params Edge[] edges) {
        foreach (var edge in edges) {
            edge.Node1.Parent = this;
            edge.Node2.Parent = this;
        }
    }
}

class Node {
    public Graph Parent { get; set; }

    public List<Node> GetNeighbours()
    {
        var neighbors = new List<Node>();
        foreach(var edge in parent.Edges) { 
            if (edge.Node1 == this && !neighbors.Contains(edge.Node2)) {
                neighbors.Add(edge.Node2);
            }
            else if (edge.Node2 == this && !neighbors.Contains(edge.Node1)) {
                neighbors.Add(edge.Node1);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Edge {
    public Node Node1 { get; set; }
    public Node Node2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would like to point out that this approach has quite a high time complexity (looping over all edges of the graph + 2 Contains calls to neighbors list). Something like O(n-squared).

Comment: I should have used a `HashSet` instead so I didn't need the `Contains` method

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach. Instead of passing the parent reference, you could make each edge aware of the nodes on each end. And make each node aware of the edges connected to them.

A massive advantage of this is that you do not need enumerate possibly massive amounts of nodes/edges to find what you need. You already have what you need so it is much faster.

Here is quick sample of the approach I described along with some tests:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace GraphModelTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestA();
            TestB();
            TestC();
        }

        private static void TestC()
        {
            //A <-> B
            //|     |
            //D <-> C
            Node a = new Node("a");
            Node b = new Node("b");
            Node c = new Node("c");
            Node d = new Node("d");
            Edge ab = a.ConnectTo(b);
            Edge bc = b.ConnectTo(c);
            Edge cd = c.ConnectTo(d);
            Edge da = d.ConnectTo(a);
            Graph g = new Graph();
            g.Nodes.Add(a);
            g.Nodes.Add(b);
            g.Nodes.Add(c);
            g.Nodes.Add(d);
            g.Edges.Add(ab);
            g.Edges.Add(bc);
            g.Edges.Add(cd);
            g.Edges.Add(da);
            Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Neighbours of B");
            foreach (Node n in b.GetNeighbours())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Neighbours of D");
            foreach (Node n in d.GetNeighbours())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void TestB()
        {
            //A <-> B <-> C
            Node a = new Node("a");
            Node b = new Node("b");
            Edge ab = a.ConnectTo(b);
            Node c = new Node("c");
            Edge bc = b.ConnectTo(c);
            Graph g = new Graph();
            g.Nodes.Add(a);
            g.Nodes.Add(b);
            g.Nodes.Add(c);
            g.Edges.Add(ab);
            g.Edges.Add(bc);
            Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("Neighbours of B");
            foreach (Node n in b.GetNeighbours())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n.ToString());
            }
        }

        private static void TestA()
        {
            //A <-> B
            Node a = new Node("a");
            Node b = new Node("b");
            Edge ab = a.ConnectTo(b);
            Graph g = new Graph();
            g.Nodes.Add(a);
            g.Nodes.Add(b);
            g.Edges.Add(ab);
            Console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
        }
    }

    class Edge
    {
        public Edge(string name, Node a, Node b)
        {
            Name = name;
            A = a;
            B = b;
        }

        public Node A { get; private set; }
        public Node B { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Name}";
    }

    class Node
    {
        public Node(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            connectedEdges = new List<Edge>();
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        private ICollection<Edge> connectedEdges;
        public IEnumerable<Edge> ConnectedEdges
        {
            get
            {
                return connectedEdges.AsEnumerable();
            }
        }

        public void AddConnectedEdge(Edge e)
        {
            connectedEdges.Add(e);
        }

        public Edge ConnectTo(Node n)
        {
            //Create the edge with references to nodes
            Edge e = new Edge($"{Name} <-> {n.Name}", this, n);
            //Add edge reference to this node
            AddConnectedEdge(e);
            //Add edge reference to the other node
            n.AddConnectedEdge(e);
            return e;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Node> GetNeighbours()
        {
            foreach (Edge e in ConnectedEdges)
            {
                //Have to figure which one is not this node
                Node node = e.A != this ? e.A : e.B;
                yield return node;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Name}";
    }

    class Graph
    {
        public Graph()
        {
            Nodes = new List<Node>();
            Edges = new List<Edge>();
        }

        public ICollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Edge> Edges { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

            str.AppendLine("Graph:");
            str.AppendLine("Nodes:");
            foreach (Node n in Nodes)
            {
                str.AppendLine(n.ToString());
            }
            str.AppendLine("Edges:");
            foreach (Edge e in Edges)
            {
                str.AppendLine(e.ToString());
            }

            return str.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will definitely take a closer look at this code :) in fact now I only have references from `Edge`'s perspective (it has a start and end node inside). I think I've done that this way because it's obvious - you *need* to know where does the edge start and end.